# In parallel computing, why using all threads (4) execution time is longer than using only a half (2)?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, gfortran

E.g, I'm using this code (CPU: 4 cores (thread per core)):

```
program main
use omp_lib
implicit none
integer, parameter:: ma=100, n=10000, mb= 100
integer:: istart, iend 
real, dimension (ma,n) :: a 
real, dimension (n,mb) :: b
real, dimension (ma,mb) :: c = 0. 

integer:: i,j,k, threads=2, ppt, thread_num

integer:: toc, tic, rate 
real:: time_parallel, time 

call random_number (a) 
call random_number (b)


!/////////////////////// 1- PARALLEL PRIVATE ///////////////////////
CALL system_clock(count_rate=rate)
call system_clock(tic)

ppt = ma/threads
  !$ call omp_set_num_threads(threads)
  
  !$omp parallel default(shared) private(istart, iend, &
  !$omp thread_num, i)
  
    !$ thread_num = omp_get_thread_num()
    !$ istart = thread_num*ppt +1 
    !$ iend = min(ma, thread_num*ppt + ppt) 

  do i= istart,iend
    do j= 1,mb
      do k= 1,n
        c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k)*b(k,j)
      end do 
    end do
  end do 
  
!$omp end parallel
print*, 'Result in parallel mode' 
!$ print*, c(85:90,40)  
  
call system_clock(toc)
time_parallel = real(toc-tic)/real(rate)


!/////////////////////// 2-normal execution ///////////////////////
 c = 0
CALL system_clock(count_rate=rate)
call system_clock(tic)

  call system_clock(tic)

  do i= 1,ma
    do j= 1,mb
      do k= 1,n
        c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k)*b(k,j)
      end do 
    end do
  end do 
  
  
call system_clock(toc)
time =  real(toc-tic)/real(rate)
print*, 'Result in serial mode'
print*, c(85:90,40)  
print*, '------------------------------------------------'
print*, 'Threads: ', threads, '|  Time Parallel Private', time_parallel, 's '
print*, '                         Time Normal  ', time, 's'
!----------------------------------------------------------------


end program main
```

I get the following results:

First execution:

```
 Result in parallel mode

   2477.89478       2528.50391       2511.84204       2528.12061       2500.79517       
2510.69971    

 Result in serial mode

   2477.89478       2528.50391       2511.84204       2528.12061       2500.79517       
2510.69971    


 Threads:            2 |  Time Parallel Private  0.379999995     s 

 Time Normal    0.603999972     s
```

Second execution:

```
 Result in parallel mode

   2492.20679       2496.56152       2500.58203       2516.51685       2516.43604       
2530.71313    

 Result in serial mode

   2492.20679       2496.56152       2500.58203       2516.51685       2516.43604       
2530.71313    

 ------------------------------------------------

 Threads:            4 |  Time Parallel Private   1.11500001     s 

 Time Normal    0.486000001     s
```

It was compiled using:

```
gfortran -Wall -fopenmp -g -O2 -o prog.exe prueba.f90 
./prog.exe
```

Comment: Arre you really sure you have actual 4 cores. Or is it some kind of hyperthreading? What is the CPU model you use? The difference in the "normal" runtime is suspicious. Make also sure that the CPU has enough time to get to speed.

Comment: @VladimirF The model is AMD A6-6310.

Comment: I assume it is all down to memory bandwidth. You are not going to get more performance without a serious re-write with loop tiling or similar tricks. Making an efficient matrix multiplication is hard and is not really a task for a beginner.

Comment: Sorry I don't get you if you don't specify.

Comment: BTW with `gfortran -O3 -funroll-loops` I actually get a decent speedup for "normal".

Comment: @VladimirF I compiled with this flags and it takes more time. Unroll loops is not useful sometimes.

Comment: Sometimes not, but it took much less time for me. At least for "normal". I did try it.

Comment: What is your cpu model?

Comment: Intel i7-3770         .

Comment: @Isaac I also think memory bandwidth limitation, but isn't a bit better to rearrange loops to the order j -> k -> i (so parallelizing j) rather than the current i -> j -> k ? (though it may depend on array shapes...) the former gave me a bit better performance on core-i7 (4-core, 2012, old...). Also options like gfortran-10 -O2 -pipe -march=native -mtune=native -funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=4 -ftree-vectorize -Wall might give some speedup (which I learned from steve kargl on the net)

Comment: On my computer with 6 cores / 12 threads, I obtained 0.16 to 0.18 seconds in serial and 0.10 s with 2 threads, 0.06 seconds with 4 threads and 0.04 seconds with 12 threads.  Whether or not the parallelization is optimum, it is doing something and gives a useful speedup.   I didn't observe 4 threads to be worse than 2.

Comment: @roygvib I know that a different order improve performance, but I choose an example that requires a relative high execution time (seconds) because I want to make tests in parallel.  By the way, I tried your flags and took an execution time several times higher, maybe it depends on computer that you use.

Comment: @M.S.B. Maybe because I'm using more background programs.

Comment: @Isaac the ideas of code performance and total execution time are getting muddled here. As you say, for testing you want code which has a relatively high execution time, but this should still be optimised code. If code is not optimised then the runtime may be dominated by things like memory access and passing data between CPU cores, rather than by raw CPU processing time. If code is very poorly optimised then the time taken to pass data between cores (which increases with the number of cores) can be larger than the time taken to process that data. This might be what you are seeing here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have N cores and using N threads than some of your threads get switched out for some other process and threads. So it's preferable to use less number threads than the available cores.

Comment: One often has the whole computer just for that one computation. The OS and related services still do their job, but it is pretty negligible.

Comment: This depends on the context. In the context of high-performance computing, when you typically have an entire computer (or node on a supercomputer) available for your process then with well-optimised you can regularly achieve >99% usage of each core. In this case, using less threads than the number of cores available makes no sense.